# is it possible I imported my wallet "Keystore" file and somehow the password files not included?

Tags: private-key, import, password, keystore

I tried running My Ethereum Wallet on my windows P.C, created a wallet and had some ETH sent to it. Then for some reason I waited and waited but the software just would not sync. So, I stored the Keystore file, uninstalled the software and then installed mist, and went on to import the last wallets address from kestore file.
Now that Mist has fully synced, my ETH do show as in the account. However when I try to send or move ETH it wont accept my password as correct. I run test and get the following. see below.

So my question is: is it possible to import the account and lose the password recognition aspect of it along the way somehow ?

```
Permissions
permissions
should be available ‣
AssertionError: The permissions object was not present, please reload the test page: expected undefined to be an array
    at Context.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/spec/permissions-spec.js:9:55)
    at Test.Runnable.run (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:4281:32)
    at Runner.runTest (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:4667:10)
    at file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:4743:12
    at next (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:4592:14)
    at file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:4602:7
    at next (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:4540:23)
    at file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:4569:5
    at timeslice (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:5613:27)
web3.eth.accounts
should return an array [sync] ‣
should return an array [async]200ms ‣
should match the allowed accounts in the tabs permisssions, and don't contain coinbase [sync] ‣
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Context.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/spec/permissions-spec.js:32:47)
    at Test.Runnable.run (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:4264:15)
    at Runner.runTest (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:4667:10)
    at file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:4743:12
    at next (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:4592:14)
    at file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:4602:7
    at next (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:4540:23)
    at file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:4569:5
    at timeslice (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:5613:27)
should match the allowed accounts in the tabs permisssions, and don't contain coinbase [async] ‣
Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/spec/permissions-spec.js:43)
    at global.onerror (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:5594:10)
should match the allowed accounts in the tabs permisssions, and don't contain coinbase [async, batch request] ‣
Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/spec/permissions-spec.js:58)
    at global.onerror (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:5594:10)
web3.eth.coinbase
should be empty [sync] ‣
AssertionError: expected '0x01f5efa14109df947a3c83a6d7cc5f9c87cbf35f' to be null
    at Context.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/spec/permissions-spec.js:82:35)
    at Test.Runnable.run (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:4281:32)
    at Runner.runTest (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:4667:10)
    at file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:4743:12
    at next (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:4592:14)
    at file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:4602:7
    at next (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:4540:23)
    at file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:4569:5
    at timeslice (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:5613:27)
should be empty [async] ‣
Error: Uncaught AssertionError: expected '0x01f5efa14109df947a3c83a6d7cc5f9c87cbf35f' to be null (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/chai.js:206)
    at global.onerror (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:5594:10)
should be empty [async, batch request] ‣
Error: Uncaught AssertionError: expected '0x01f5efa14109df947a3c83a6d7cc5f9c87cbf35f' to be null (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/chai.js:206)
    at global.onerror (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mist/resources/app.asar/tests/mocha-in-browser/lib/mocha.js:5594:10)
```

Comment: Please be more clear on how the first account was generated. You mention "My Ethereum Wallet", is that the Officiall Ethereum wallet that can be found here: https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases? The .json file in keystore should have the correct format to be moved between applications (unless it was corrupted somehow).

Answer (score 2):

Your keystore file should contain your private key in encrypted format and your password is used to unlock the private key for making actions on the account. There is no separate password file so it is more likely that you are using the wrong password or something is wrong with the file itself.